# Wait until two different users click a button and then go to a page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hi working on a website project where I want to wait until two separate users click a button and then have them both go to the same page. These users will be each in their own browser window.
I have searched the internet and went to research ajax but found that is not what I am looking for because I want the page to automatically detect when the other user in a different browser clicked the button, instead of having a user repeatedly click a button to see if another user has clicked there button such as with ajax. Please help thanks.

**Goal: Have a user be automatically redirected to another page once a *different* user clicks the same button in a different window**

> Example:
>
> user 1 and user 2 are both on a website
>
> user 1 clicks on a button.  user 1 is now waiting on a waiting page
>   until another person clicks on the button in a different browser
>   window.
>
> user 2 now clicks on the button in their own browser window
>
> user 1 and user 2 now get automatically redirected to the same page.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `ajax` if it's not what you're looking for? Also, please post the code you already have, Stack Overflow is a [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
& [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) website for specific programming questions.

Comment: You can make it in few ways. But all of them require some server with knowledge about it's users. Your backend should know each user identifier. Is it okay for you? There are no other ways to do it without backend.

In all situations you make some request to your server, saying "Used with id %user_id% clicked needed button". And when second user makes same action, you have to tell your frontends to redirect users.

Comment: [Where should I use Blockquotes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306035/231583)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner don't you think that's a bit petty? The example helps to improve the readability of the question and makes it better for those trying to understand it . If you think it could be improved feel free to edit it and contribute, otherwise your comment doesn't help or address the question at hand.

Comment: @kerbholz because not everyone knows everything, and I figured someone may think ajax was a better solution. if you don't like it feel free to contribute. and edit the post.

Comment: "_doesn't help or address the question at hand_" To be fair, there isn't even a question here.

Comment: @Nikita yes that is exactly what I am looking for. I want to change the front end as described in the post. How can we do this? Can you submit an answer?

Comment: Not only is this question too broad, it's also unclear. I'm with @kerbholz on this one. The basic logic here is `if(condition==x){...}else{...}`. Please try something, it stands to be easier to help then.

Comment: @kerbholz Thanks for the input. feel free to edit it to make it better. Do you know how to solve the situation presented in the post? What do you think is the best solution to solve the situation?.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thanks for the constructive feedback.  I am unsure what to try, that is why im here. I have looked up ajax was apparently not what I needed. I'm unsure what to use to accomplish this. that is why I'm here. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this done you definitely should have some backend, that knows about frontend users. So, next ways of doing it: websockets.
Each user entering your frontend opens channel with backend. So, as soon as user clicks the button, you just send information about it on your server through sockets and store it on server. Than your server should wait till second user makes same action. When second user clicks the button, server should send in both of these chanels (to first and second user) some data, that will tell browser to redirect the user. Can describe you it in steps:

1. User1 enters site, browser creates connection with backend, server stores ID of this user;
2. User2 enters site, browser creates connection with backend server stores ID of this user;
3. User1 clicks button, browser tells backend that User1 clicks button;
4. Server stores info like { user1: true, user2: false } (meaning that user1 clicked button, user2 - dont);
5. User2 clicks button, server gets info;
6. Server sends in channels of User1 and User2 data like { canRedirect: true };
7. both browsers make redirect.

This is the simplest and best way to do it.
In other way you can read about long-polling. Same here but not best way to use HTTP for your task.

Comment: Thank you. that is constructive and is leading me in the right direction. Thanks! :)